# self controller 0 key/value pairs

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a working controller, however when I debug it and try to see the values of the variables, self is empty like this. I tryed to clean project,
restarted XCODE but nothing worked, any idea?

[image]

Comment: The Xcode debugger is quite bad sometimes, what exactly are you looking for in `self`?

Comment: I am using a NSArray declared in .h file, but when I am trying to init it, it doesnt work, seems like self is the problem

Comment: Means you faced problem in array?

Comment: are you talking about `listaAccesos`? Have you tried logging it? Maybe add a breakpoint in `viewDidAppear` and inspect `self` there to see if the property has been initialized correclty

Comment: yes it is listaAccesos, I tryed what you said , still same result in self in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear

Comment: How are you declaring `listaAccesos`? Shouldn't you be accessing it through `self.listaAccesos` instead?

Comment: I just copy and paste everything in a new code and everything work as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created another controller, copy and paste everything and it just worked

Answer (score 0):

initialize you variable in viewDidLoad.

for ex.
if you have declared NSMutableArray in properties and haven't intialized them in viewDidLoad.
like this i.e.NSMutableArray a=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

It may cause this problem.